# Is it possible to have UserDefined values for RowId in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

Is it possible to have custom defined values for @rid in OrientDB?
Say in class Vehicle, i want my rid to be vehicle number

Is there any way to have user defined Ids?

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible. @rid is generated by the database and identifies the position of the record (clusterId + clusterPosition)

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Tutorial-Record-ID.html